# How to access XML data with Coldfusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion

A client wants me to add a weather forecast to his web site. The official weather report comes in an XML file and I need help accessing some of the elements in the file.

I can download the two XML files that contain the data needed on the site, and I can parse them into ColdFusion XML variables.

I can extract the data I need from the top levels, but it's lower levels that are causing me some heartburn. The XML files contain weather observations and forecasts for every location in the state. We don't need that - we just want to access the data about my client's location.

Here's a sample of the XML data I'm talking about

```
<area aac="NSW_PT123" description="Richmond" type="location" parent-aac="NSW_PW005">
        <forecast-period index="0" start-time-local="2021-10-16T17:00:00+11:00" end-time-local="2021-10-17T00:00:00+11:00" start-time-utc="2021-10-16T06:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2021-10-16T13:00:00Z">
            <element type="forecast_icon_code">2</element>
            <text type="precis">Clear.</text>
            <text type="probability_of_precipitation">5%</text>
        </forecast-period>
        <forecast-period index="1" start-time-local="2021-10-17T00:00:00+11:00" end-time-local="2021-10-18T00:00:00+11:00" start-time-utc="2021-10-16T13:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2021-10-17T13:00:00Z">
            <element type="forecast_icon_code">1</element>
            <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">7</element>
            <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">24</element>
            <text type="precis">Sunny.</text>
            <text type="probability_of_precipitation">0%</text>
        </forecast-period>
        <forecast-period index="2" start-time-local="2021-10-18T00:00:00+11:00" end-time-local="2021-10-19T00:00:00+11:00" start-time-utc="2021-10-17T13:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2021-10-18T13:00:00Z">
            <element type="forecast_icon_code">1</element>
            <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">7</element>
            <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">28</element>
            <text type="precis">Sunny.</text>
            <text type="probability_of_precipitation">5%</text>
        </forecast-period>
```

In this snippet, `index="0"` indicates 'today' and `index="1"` indicates 'tomorrow'. The client wants outlook for 7 days.

So currently out of all that XML data I need to identify which day it's about, the icon code (for the pretty pictures) and the Precis (usually a single word or short phrase), probability_of_precipitation (is it gonna rain?)  and the times. The rest I can throw away.

In another file with similar structure, there's a long form forecast for another version of the page.

I've been able to access the attributes in the first line (`aac` and `description`) but what I need help with is how to access the forecast-period elements under that line.  There are `forecast-period` elements for all the other districts too, which we don't want to access.

I get to this part of the XML file with the ColdFusion XmlSearch/XPATH expression

```
XmlSearch(IDN10064XML, "//area[@aac='NSW_PT123']")
```

So here's my question.  In the example code above, (which i have no control over - it's what the government puts out) how do I create a variable that will give me the results

- `"Clear."` from the above precis element?
- `"5%"` from the probability of precipitation element?
- `"2"` from the forecast_icon_code element?

Comment: We use the Dark Sky API (formerly Forecast.io) for weather, but they are no longer accepting new signups and I have until the end of 2022 to find a replacement.  Which service are you using?

Comment: I'm in Australia.  I use the Bureau Of Meteorology - a free government run API if all you want is the basic forecast.   It's no use for us to use non-government based APIs because their data differs from the official government forecast - and they've paid millions of our taxpayer dollars to get it all modelled.    I am assuming Dark Sky is USA based although there is no indication on their web site where their observations are all done.  But Australia's weather is so unique i doubt if anyone based outside of Australia would be able to give anything better than a stab in the dark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<cffunction name="WeatherForecast" returntype="struct">
  <cfargument name="weatherData" type="xml" required="yes">
  <cfargument name="areaCode" type="string" required="yes">

  <cfset var areas = XmlSearch(weatherData, "//area[@aac='#areaCode#']")>
  <cfif ArrayLen(areas) eq 0>
    <cfthrow message="WeatherForecast: area code #areaCode# not found.">
  </cfif>
  
  <cfset var textOnly = function (node) {
    return node.XmlType == 'ATTRIBUTE' ? node.XmlValue : node.XmlText;
  }>

  <cfreturn {
    icons: XmlSearch(areas[1], "./forecast-period/element[@type='forecast_icon_code']").map(textOnly),
    precis: XmlSearch(areas[1], "./forecast-period/text[@type='precis']").map(textOnly),
    precipitation: XmlSearch(areas[1], "./forecast-period/text[@type='probability_of_precipitation']").map(textOnly)
  }>
</cffunction>
```

Usage:

```
<cfset IDN10064XML = XmlParse(weatherXml, true)>
<cfset forecast = WeatherForecast(IDN10064XML, "NSW_PT123")>
```

returns this struct:

```
{
    "PRECIPITATION": ["5%", "0%", "5%"],
    "PRECIS": ["Clear.", "Sunny.", "Sunny."],
    "ICONS": ["2", "1", "1"]
}
```

Each part will contain as many values as there are `<forecast-period>` elements for that `<area>` in the XML, in the order they appear in the XML. In other words, `forecast.precipitation[1]` will refer to "today", unless there is a chance that the XML ever arrives out of order (I doubt it).

Things like the time attribute values can be extracted in the same way:

```
XmlSearch(areas[1], "./forecast-period/@start-time-local").map(textOnly)
```

Comment: Im sorry I've taken so long to come back to you - life has intervened and I have been away doing another project until today.  

I am delighted to say that when I looked carefully at the sample code you put up,  Tomalak,   that there was a clanging sound as the penny dropped and suddenly I understood what was going on.    I have now finished the coding part of my project and I have to work on the graphics and other presentation elements.       

When a user comes to the home page of the web site they're going to see the latest version of the weather forecast.

Comment: @MikeKear That's the most encouraging feedback I've got on this site in quite a while. Thank you/you're very welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer converting simple XML to JSON and then using regular struct/array handling.

You can convert XML to JSON in Adobe ColdFusion using 1 line of code.

```
<cfset myJSONObject = createObject("java","org.json.XML").toJSONObject(XMLText)>
<cfdump var="#myJSONObject#">
```

For more examples, check out the sample CFML here:
https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/00bb362672f772fab56d26f3e01ad3fa

Comment: XML has the advantage of providing XPath as a easy way for complex searching and filtering, a thing that JSON is lacking. XML largely behaves like arrays and structs in CF anyway - both indexing and dot paths are possible: `weatherXml.area['forecast-period'][1].text[2].XmlText` = `5%`

Comment: After using the undocumented XML-to-JSON, the result can be referenced similarly as weatherJson.area['forecast-period'][1].text[2].content.  While an XML object may be able to be accessed like an array or struct, you can't natively loop over an XML object as easily... a thing that CFML is lacking.

Comment: Of course you can. Things like `<cfloop array="#weatherXml.area['forecast-period']#" item="p">` work just fine.

Comment: Hmm... You can also loop over "area" as a collection.  TBH, this functionality may not have been available in older versions of ACF, so I probably hadn't ever tried it and most of the APIs that we use support JSON.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Possible. I think looping over XML as an array was always possible, even in versions as old as CF7, but I might remember it wrong.